# ComputeCpp on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, opencl, sycl

I recently installed ComputeCpp version 1.3 and I started a ComputeCpp project on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. It came with the following sample code.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  SYCL Sample Code
//
//  Author: Codeplay, April 2015
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*!
If you encounter an application cannot start because SYCL.dll or SYCL_d.dll is
missing error, then you may have to restart your computer in order to update the
environment variable COMPUTECPPROOT.
*/

#include <CL/sycl.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace cl::sycl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  /* Create 1024 element arrays for input data and output. */
  float inputDataA[1024];
  float inputDataB[1024];
  float outputData[1024];

  /* Initialize input data with values and output data with zeroes. */
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    inputDataA[i] = (float)i;
    inputDataB[i] = (float)(1024 - i);
    outputData[i] = 0.0f;
  }

  /* Wrap all SYCL structures and function calls with a try-catch block to catch
   * SYCL exceptions. */
  try {

    /* Create a default_selector to select a device to execute on. */
    default_selector mySelector;

    /* Create a queue from the default_selector to create an implicit context
     * and queue to execute with. */
    queue myQueue(mySelector);

    /* Create a scope to control data synchronisation of buffer objects. */
    {
      /* Create 1 dimensionsal buffers for the input and output data of size
       * 1024. */
      buffer<float, 1> inputBufferA(inputDataA, range<1>(1024));
      buffer<float, 1> inputBufferB(inputDataB, range<1>(1024));
      buffer<float, 1> outputBuffer(outputData, range<1>(1024));

      /* Submit a command_group to execute from the queue. */
      myQueue.submit([&](handler &cgh) {

        /* Create accessors for accessing the input and output data within the
         * kernel. */
        auto inputPtrA = inputBufferA.get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
        auto inputPtrB = inputBufferB.get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
        auto outputPtr = outputBuffer.get_access<access::mode::write>(cgh);

        /* Enqueue a kernel called 'vector_add', with a global work size of {
         * 16, 8, 8 } and a local work size of { 4, 2, 2 }. */
        cgh.parallel_for<class vector_add>(
            nd_range<3>(range<3>(16, 8, 8), range<3>(4, 2, 2)),
            [=](nd_item<3> item) {

              /* Retreive the linear global id for the current work item. */
              size_t idx = item.get_global_linear_id();

              /* Use the linear global id to add the respective element of each
               * input accessor together and assign them to the respective
               * element of the output accessor. */
              outputPtr[idx] = inputPtrA[idx] + inputPtrB[idx];
            });
      });
    }

  } catch (exception e) {

    /* In the case of an exception being throw, print theerror message and
     * return 1. */
    std::cout << e.what();
    return 1;
  }

  /* Sum up all the values in the output array. */
  float sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    sum += outputData[i];
  }

  /* If the sum is the expected result, return 0, else return 1. */
  if (sum == (1024.0f * 1024)) {
    std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Fail: Expected result was 1024.0f, actual result is " << sum
              << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

When I run it, I got the following errors.

```
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/common.h(109,20): error : no type named 'int8_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'int8_t'?
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor_args.h(1077,11): error : no type named 'plane_id_t' in namespace 'cl::sycl::detail'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1350,3): error : no type named 'int8_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'int8_t'?
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1512,57): error : 'is_image_ctr' is a protected member of 'cl::sycl::detail::accessor_common<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1514,24): error : 'is_image_array_ctr' is a protected member of 'cl::sycl::detail::accessor_common<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1515,62): error : 'is_host_image_ctr' is a protected member of 'cl::sycl::detail::accessor_common<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1516,58): error : 'is_atomic_ctr' is a protected member of 'cl::sycl::detail::accessor_common<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1512,57): error : 'is_image_ctr' is a protected member of 'cl::sycl::detail::accessor_common<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::write, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1514,24): error : 'is_image_array_ctr' is a protected member of 'cl::sycl::detail::accessor_common<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::write, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1515,62): error : 'is_host_image_ctr' is a protected member of 'cl::sycl::detail::accessor_common<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::write, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1516,58): error : 'is_atomic_ctr' is a protected member of 'cl::sycl::detail::accessor_common<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::write, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
main.cpp(75,58): error : type 'const cl::sycl::accessor<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>' does not provide a subscript operator
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1541,9): error : type 'cl::sycl::accessor<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>::accessor_common' (aka 'accessor_common<float, 1, (cl::sycl::access::mode)0U, (cl::sycl::access::target)1U, access::placeholder::false_t>') is not a direct or virtual base of 'cl::sycl::accessor<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\SYCL/accessor.h(1541,9): error : type 'cl::sycl::accessor<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::write, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>::accessor_common' (aka 'accessor_common<float, 1, (cl::sycl::access::mode)1U, (cl::sycl::access::target)1U, access::placeholder::false_t>') is not a direct or virtual base of 'cl::sycl::accessor<float, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::write, cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer, cl::sycl::access::placeholder::false_t>'
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\ComputeCpp.targets(60,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\bin\compute++.exe" -D_SIZE_T_DEFINED -Wno-ignored-attributes -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -sycl -O2 -nobuiltininc -I"c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" -I"c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\atlmfc\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\include\image_library" -I"C:\vector_sum\\" -o"C:\vector_sum\main.sycl" -c main.cpp " exited with code 1.
```

As we can see it is related to the header files that came with the installation which leads me to believe the errors have something to do with the compilers.

In the guide for ComputeCpp it says the following:
"Your Visual Studio install may be missing the required C++ tools and configurations, you can check this by modifying your install from add/remove programs."
I wonder what tools and configurations I could be missing in my installation of Visual Studio 2015.
https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/platform-support/targeting-windows

Edit: After I added `#include <cstdint>` as suggested, all those errors were resolved. The build became successful. However, when executed, I got the following errors.

```
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\vector_sum\x64\Debug\vector_sum.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Codeplay\ComputeCpp\lib\ComputeCpp_vs2015_d.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IntelOpenCL64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\intelocl64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DXCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\task_executor64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\cpu_device64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\tbb\tbb.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdrcl64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdfcl64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dbghelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdbcl64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vector_sum.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdusc64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD9C14A799 in vector_sum.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cl::sycl::compile_program_error at memory location 0x00000040BA8F7340.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD9C14A799 in vector_sum.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x00000040BA8F4120.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD9C14A799 in vector_sum.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cl::sycl::compile_program_error at memory location 0x00000040BA8F08C0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD9C14A799 in vector_sum.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cl::sycl::compile_program_error at memory location 0x00000040BA8F0730.
The thread 0x30dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1b98 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x3c18 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1a74 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[7532] vector_sum.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

When running it on the command prompt, I got the following error.

```
Error: [ComputeCpp:RT0100] Failed to build program (<Build log for program 000002179AB4B9D0 device 0 (size 106):
error: unknown metadata record encountered: kernel_arg_addr_space
error: midlevel compiler failed build.
```

Here is what I got to check hardware support.

```
********************************************************************************

ComputeCpp Info (CE 1.3.0)

SYCL 1.2.1 revision 3

********************************************************************************


Device Info:

Discovered 2 devices matching:
  platform    : <any>
  device type : <any>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 0:

  Device is supported                     : NO - No bitcode target found
  Bitcode targets                         :
  CL_DEVICE_NAME                          :         Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2127U @ 1.90GHz
  CL_DEVICE_VENDOR                        : Intel(R) Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION                       : 3.0.1.10891
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE                          : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 1:

  Device is supported                     : NO - No bitcode target found
  Bitcode targets                         :
  CL_DEVICE_NAME                          : Intel(R) HD Graphics
  CL_DEVICE_VENDOR                        : Intel(R) Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION                       : 10.18.10.5129
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE                          : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU

If you encounter problems when using any of these OpenCL devices, please consult
this website for known issues:
https://computecpp.codeplay.com/releases/v1.3.0/platform-support-notes

********************************************************************************
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `int8_t` is in `#include <cstdint>`.  Is this file being included?

Comment: It wasn't included in the header files.

Comment: It is a [C++ standard header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) -- every standard C++ compiler has it.  Either the SYCL library has a line that `#include`'s it, or you have to #include it before the SYCL header

Comment: I updated my question. That fixed those errors.

Comment: It looks like there is something not quite right here. Possibly you didn't select the required pre-requisites during installation. In any case, can you try following these instructions that use CMake to validate the set up? https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/platform-support/targeting-windows

Comment: I provided another update. It is about hardware support. I wonder if ```NO - No bitcode target found``` maybe the problem.